# SSIS - Create Batch File to Run Package

Tags: batch-file, ssis-2008

*****Update*** Also, I have tested utilizing the same database. (extract from one table into another in the same database and it was successful)

New error: Code 0xc029303
Source: Package Connection Manager "Rpt"
Description: The request OLEDB provider ORAOLEDB.1 is not registered. IF the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 32-bit moded

Perhaps it has to do with the multiple connections from Oracle db to SQL db?

FYI: First time creating a Batch file and trying to auto run a SSIS package

Project:
Extract data (one table) from one database (Oracle) to SQL Server, auto execution update, daily.

Short term goal:
Create Batch file and have file execute SSIS package. The SSIS package runs in SSIS with no warnings or errors.

Properties I have changed:

```
  Max Error Count 10
Delay Validation = True
Force Exec Type = Int64
Run 64 BtRunTime = False
```

I have created a Batch file, see below

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110   \DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /f  "C:\Users\J\Desktop\Si\Si\Package.dtsx"
```

From the CMD I receive the below error:

```
Code: 0xc0047017
Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
Description: RPT Vendor Data failed Validation and returned error code      0xc020801c
End Error
Progress: 2017-03-20
Source Data Flow Task
Validating: 50% complete
End Progress.
Error: 2017-03-20
Code: 0xc004700c
Source Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
Description: One or more components failed validation
End Error
Error: 2017-03-20
Code:0xc0024107
Source Data Flow Task
Desc There were errors during task validation
End Error
DTExec: The pacakge execution returned DTSER_SUCCES <0>
```

Comment: is there a log that I can check for a more detailed summary of the error?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to adjust the Batch file to relect 32 bit (x86). File below:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /f "C:\Users\J\Desktop\lth\Package.dtsx"
```